# SQL Calculating Moving Average Crossover of variable lengths

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate moving averages crossover with variable dates.

My database is structured:

```
id
stock_id
date
closing_price
```

And:

```
stock_id
symbol
```

For example, I'd like to find out if the average price going back X days ever gets greater than the average price going back Y days within the past Z days. Each of those time periods is variable. This needs to be run for every stock in the database (about 3000 stocks with prices going back 100 years).

I'm a bit stuck on this, what I currently have is a mess of SQL subqueries that don't work because they cant account for the fact that X, Y, and Z can all be any value (0-N). That is, in the past 5 days I could be looking for a stock where the 40 day average is > than 5, or the 5 > 40. Or I could be looking over the past 40 days to find stocks where the 10 day moving average is > 30 day moving average.

This question is different from the other questions as there is variable short and long dates as well as a variable term.

Answer (score 0):

Please find see these earlier posts on Stackoverflow:

- [How to calculated multiple moving average in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059693/how-to-calculated-multiple-moving-average-in-mysql)
- [Calculate moving averages in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784027/calculate-moving-averages-in-sql)

These posts have solutions to your question.

Comment: This question is different from the other questions as there is variable short and long dates as well as a variable term.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most direct way to do a moving average in MySQL is using a correlated subquery.  Here is an example:

```
select p.*,
       (select avg(closing_price)
        from prices p2
        where p2.stock_id = p.stock_id and
              p2.date between p.date - interval x day and pdate
       ) as MvgAvg_X,
       (select avg(closing_price)
        from prices p2
        where p2.stock_id = p.stock_id and
              p2.date between p.date - interval y day and pdate
       ) as MvgAvg_Y
from prices p
```

You need to fill in the values for `x` and `y`.

For performance reasons, you will want an index on `prices(stock_id, date, closing_price)`.

If you have an option for another database, Oracle, Postgres, and SQL Server 2012 all offer much better performing solutions for this problem.

In Postgres, you can write this as:

```
select p.*,
       avg(p.price) over (partition by stock_id rows x preceding) as AvgX,
       avg(p.price) over (partition by stock_id rows y preceding) as AvgY
from p
```

Comment: I have the option of Postgres...is it really that much faster?

Also that seems to work for part of the problem, but not the full problem. It does not account for Z---that is, this occuring in the past X days. 

Also, remember X and Y could swap. This is my sticking point.

Comment: Example: I would want this query to be able to find both the 10 day moving average crossing over 50 day moving average within the past 5 days AND the 50 day crossing UNDER 10 day moving average within the past 5 days.

Each of those numbers, X,Y, and Z are variable.

Comment: You would calculate the moving averages in a subquery and then put the logic in the surrounding query.

Comment: This query is taking hours to run...wow. With a tuned db

Comment: @user1797484 . . . Do you have the appropriate indexes?

Comment: Yes, btree on each  prices(stock_id, date, closing_price)

Comment: There should be three seperate indexes right? Not an index containing all 3 cols? or does it not matter?

Comment: @user1797484 . . . It matters a great deal.  There should be one index with the three columns.

Comment: Okay, I read up on indexes a bit and created the index with the cols in order: stock_id, date, adj_close. 

Running this query and I still have not gotten anything returned after HOURS! The box has an 8 core CPU and 16 gigs of ram...the db is stored on a SSD!

 select p.*,
(select avg(adj_close)
from daily_data p2
where p2.stock_id = p.stock_id and
p2.date between p.date - interval 5 day and p.date
) as MvgAvg_X,
(select avg(adj_close)
from daily_data p2
where p2.stock_id = p.stock_id and
p2.date between p.date - interval 10 day and p.date
) as MvgAvg_Y
from daily_data p

Comment: I feel like I must be missing something..please save me Mr. Gordon Linoff!

Comment: Actually I just noticed the query you wrote does not even solve the problem will it? Don't we also need to group by the stock_id so it gets us the average price for the stocks separately?