# SQL moving average with calc of average price per square metre

Tags: sql, average, moving-average

I'm trying to get a moving average for a set of real estate data that I can then graph, using MS SQL 2005.

Fields are: DateSold datetime, FloorSQM decimal(8,2), Price decimal(10,0)

What I need to do is get an average price per square metres of all the properties sold within each month as far back as we have data, which can be several years.

Therefore I need to Price/FloorSQM each property, and then apply a moving average to them for each month. Hope that makes sense.

I am completely stuck trying to figure this out, and googling endlessly is endlessly confusing.

I thought I found what I'm looking for in another post, but I keep getting "incorrect syntax near 'm'" when I try to compile it.

```
SELECT YEAR(DateSold) AS year, 
   MONTH(DateSold) AS month,
   ROUND(Euros/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),FloorSQM),2) as avg
FROM
(select s.*, DATE_ADD(DTE, INTERVAL m.i MONTH) DateSold, m.i
FROM Property s
cross join (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union 
         select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union 
         select 8 union select 9 union select 10 union select 11) m) sq
WHERE DateSold <= curdate()
GROUP BY YEAR(DateSold), MONTH(DateSold)
```

When I have this working, I then need to introduce a WHERE clause so I can limit the properties found to certain kinds (houses, apartments) and areas (New York, Los Angeles, etc)

Can anyone lend a hand please? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 isn't great at cumulative values, including moving averages.  Do you have the ability to generate the monthly results and then to process those in your reporting environment to change them in to moving averages?

Comment: What do you mean "apply a moving average to them for each month"?  Can you provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: One problem is that you are mixing Syntax from MySQL and SQL Server - `DATE_ADD` is MySQL, `DATEADD` is SQL Server. `CurDate()`  is MySQL, `GETDATE()` is SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should run, you were using some Mysql syntax:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateSold) AS year, 
       MONTH(DateSold) AS month,
       ROUND(Euros/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),FloorSQM),2) as avg
FROM (SELECT s.*, DATEADD(MONTH,m.i,DateSold) DateSold2, m.i
      FROM Property s
      cross join (select 0 i union  select 1 union  select 2 union  select 3 union 
                  select 4 union  select 5 union  select 6 union  select 7 union 
                  select 8 union  select 9 union  select 10 union  select 11
                  ) m        
     )sq
WHERE DateSold<= GETDATE()
GROUP BY YEAR(DateSold), MONTH(DateSold)
```

Not sure if it returns the desired results.

Update: I thought `DTE` was a field name, you can't have `DateSold` referenced twice in your subquery, so I changed to `DateSold2`, not sure if you intend for the `DATEADD()` result to be used in all places where `DateSold` is used, you could also just remove `DateSold` from your subquery `SELECT` list.

Comment: Hi thanks for your kind help. I get this error however: "Invalid column name 'DTE'. The column 'DateSold' was specified multiple times for 'sq'."

Comment: This is where I got the basis of my posted SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784027/calculate-moving-averages-in-sql

Comment: Oh, I thought `DTE` was a field name, it needs to be `DATEADD(unit_of_time, integer_to_add, date_field)` not sure which date you're trying to add.  You'll have to alias the `DATEADD()` result field as something other than `DateSold` since that field already exists.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just getting more confused as I'm bodging code that I got from that other page, and I don't have the knowledge to take what you've said and apply it to the code to make it work. So I'm thinking I'll get the values out into a temporary table and then apply moving average rather than trying to do it all at once, which is far beyond my capabilities at the moment. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateSold) AS year, 
   MONTH(DateSold) AS month,
   AVG(ROUND(Price/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),FloorSQM),2)) as avg
FROM property p
GROUP BY YEAR(DateSold), MONTH(DateSold);
```

Note, changed the query from Euros to Price, as you specified in the schema.

The grouping of year, month is all you need to get the average of the price for that month. You were missing the aggregate function, AVG around your formula (though might be more accurate if ROUND was wrapped around AVG). I set up a quick sample at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fe8bb/4).